# Tooltip won't show in Yii jquery button

Tags: jquery-ui, yii, tooltip

If you create a jQuery UI button in Yii, the default behavior is that the text of the button should show as the tooltip.  You can override this with the 'label' option, but neither of these works for me in Yii.  Any suggestions?  Here is the code I'm using:

```
<button id="btnClose"></button>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
    $("#btnClose").button({
        text: false,
        label: 'Close Wizard'
    });
});
</script>
```

The button shows up just fine, just without a tooltip.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A tooltip is set in the [title attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp).
The example you give us isn't Yii but plain jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
    $("#btnClose").button({
        'text': false,
        'title': 'Close Wizard'
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks.  I forgot that title is the correct attribute.